# the meaning of " unbreached"

Tags: word-meaning

> ‘I hardly minded the pain,’ he says. ‘We have all had, saving you
>   sir, as much if not worse from our fathers.’
>
> ‘True,’ he says. ‘My father beat me as if I were a sheet of metal.’
>
> ‘It was that he laid my flesh bare. And the women looking on. Dame
>   Alice. The young girls. I thought one of them might speak up for me,
>   but when they saw me **unbreached**, I only disgusted them. It made them
>   laugh. While the fellow was whipping me, they were laughing.’
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

What is the meaning of "**unbreached**"? In [the dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbreached) it says "not breached; intact", but I can't work it out in the sentence.

Comment: Could it by chance be **unbreeched**, meaning "without my **[breeches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeches)**"?

Comment: I think it really means "not breached; intact" as in your dictionary. He was being whipped, but he was unyielding. He wouldn't submit to the punishment. (That is if I'm not mistaken. It's just my guess based on a short excerpt, anyway.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. No, given the rest of the context, CopperKettle is definitely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This text is from what I'm guessing is a rather old novel. The speech in it ranges from quaint to archaic.

Long ago, what we call "pants" today where "breeches".

The narrator is speaking of a beating he got from his father - one where his father apparently first pulled down the narrator's pants.

Note also that the quoted spelling of breaches/breeches may have been the accepted one at the time. My grandfather's dictionary had entries with words spelled differently than we spell them today.